# Maven project crashing with no stacktrace or log messages with Selenium dependency

Tags: java, maven, selenium, noclassdeffounderror, dependency-management

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here with dependency management, but can't quite figure it out.

My Maven project "A" is dependent on project "B" (a gradle managed project). Both "A" and "B" also have a dependency on Selenium for UI automation. "B" is a collection of some selenium processing libraries. The selenium webDriver object is initialized in project B and returned to A, like this:

**Some class in project A**:

```
public WebDriver myDriver;
myDriver = B.initializeWebDriver(myDriver, various selenium related parameters...);
```

Then "A" can utilize the initialized myDriver object in a testNG test.
The place where it crashes in "B" with no stack trace is:

**initializeWebDriver method in project B**:

```
public WebDriver initializeWebDriver(WebDriver webDriver, ...) {
    webDriver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), cap); // <-- crashes here
    return webDriver
}
```

I would have thought that "A" and "B" would simply need to have a dependency on "selenium-java". That's all "B" has as a selenium dependency, and can create the driver and use it in various unit tests wholly contained in project B. If project A has a dependency on selenium-java, and I run a test from A, then Java immediately ends the testNG test when it reaches the line of code in "B" that instantiates the remoteWebDriver. I have a `try-catch` in both A and B, and nothing ever happens. No stack trace. No log message. Just immediately dies inside the test method in A, not jumping to a 'catch', but jumping to the 'finally' and ending.

What makes me pretty sure it's a dependency management problem, is that if I change the dependencies on "A" to selenium-api and selenium-chrome-driver and selenium-remote-driver, it works fine. But we shouldn't need to do that -- selenium-java should be fine, and selenium-java contains those other objects (selenium-api, etc) anyway! I'm guessing it's some weird CLASSDEF problem and I'm not doing dependency management correctly. I've also never seen java just blatantly give up with no stack trace or errors like this, unless it's some really weird classdef thing.

Any ideas?

**

[Edit: additional code provided as requested]

From B:

```
public WebDriver getWebDriver(WebDriver webDriver,...) {                

    try {

        System.out.println("inside B try");
        webDriver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), cap);         
        System.out.println("B instantiated webdriver");

     } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught in B");
            e.printStackTrace();

     }

    return webDriver;
}
```

From class in A:

```
try {

    System.out.println("inside A try");
    webDriver = B.getWebDriver(webDriver);
    System.out.println("webdriver A successful");

} catch (Exception e) {

      System.out.println("caught in A");
      e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    closeBrowser(webDriver);
}
```

Output from this is:

```
inside A try
inside B try
then output from the closeBrowser routine from the 'finally' in A.
```

No evidence of any exceptions or anything caught. As soon as it hits the line in B to create the remoteWebDriver, it just dies somehow with no output, and goes to the 'finally' in A.

Edit: **Fixed the problem**, I had the gradle project 'B' ensure that it was including the selenium dependency in the .jar it was exporting for project B:

```
from sourceSets.main.output
from sourceSets.main.allJava
```

... and in Maven project A, I defined the dependency on selenium-java (removed all the other various selenium jars like selenium-api, etc as this works now) as **scope:provided.**. So it's ensuring that the selenium-java dependency is in fact truly acquired from project 'B'.

But I don't understand why I couldn't have A and B both be dependent on selenium-java. They were specifying the exact same version, and I looked at the dependency resolution and they both were truly using the same version, as opposed to using a different version due to some conflict of some kind.

[edit]

The order of the dependency listed in project A's POM file is what made it work, not the gradle change or the 'provided' change. Simply listing selenium-java first in the pom before project B.

Comment: do you try-catch `Throwable` ?  Can you show the code with try-catch-finally ?

Comment: i didn't attempt to throw, but there is proof that it's not being caught anyway. Here's code/output:

Comment: where is the code/output ?

Comment: :) Sorry, added the comment before I edited the original message w/ the extra code. Supplied now. Bottom line, I think the most frustrating part was the lack of any information from java, maven, testNG, anything. Just silence and dropping out of everything to that finally block. I would have hoped for a hint from those subsystems.

Comment: You are catching Exception. Is it possible what is being thrown is an `Error` ? try catching `Throwable` instead. If that doesn't work, it really means nothing is being thrown!

Comment: When catching throwable:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder --- thanks!! Still frustrating that I can't have both projects depend on selenium-java without various trickery, but at least I've learned how to properly catch errors of this type! Thanks!!

Comment: ... and it looks like the change to gradle and 'provided' in maven had nothing to do with it working. Simply having project A have the selenium-java dependency before the dependency on project B is what does it. I thought order didn't matter. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are not getting a stacktrace. Perhaps you are terminating the program in your `closeBrowser` method? That would short-circuit the error and would explain why you are not getting uncaught exception stacktrace.

**Anyhow, for debug purpose, try the following:**

You are catching `Exception`, so `Error`s are ignored.
Change your `try-catch` to catch `Throwable`. This will ensure you catch any possible errors.

```
try{
    ...
 } catch (Throwable e) {
     System.out.println("caught in A");
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alexbt! This helped quite a bit. Upvoted, but I'm also new to stack overflow so it might not show up yet.